# ValueError: 'text' is not in list

Tags: python, list, indexing, valueerror

[image]

When I try to read my csv file with the fields text and date 
I get an error

> text_column_index = header.index('text')
>
> ValueError: 'text' is not in list

Code:

```
with open(source_file_path, 'r') as input_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_reader)
    text_column_index = header.index('text')
    date_column_index = header.index('date')
    word_frequency = {}
    for line in csv_reader:
        self.size += 1
        words = self.tokenize(line[text_column_index])
        date = line[date_column_index]
        if date > self.end_date:
            self.end_date = date
        elif date < self.start_date:
            self.start_date = date
```

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: add `print(header)` and see what it contains?

Comment: nothing happens hmm

Comment: literally nothing happens? It seems like at least the empty list should be printed

Comment: this is what I did       
            word_frequency = {}
            print(header)

Comment: Since you're getting a ValueError and not AttributeError, `header` must actually be a list. You're positive it prints absolutely nothing when you try to print, not just an empty list?

Comment: You need to add the `print` *before* the error, or else it won't reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your delimeter is actually a tab ('\t') instead of the usual comma (',') or a space (' ').
If it's any of those two, you need to change the second line accordingly.

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of is that "text" has another character like a space: "text ".